# Copy values, not formulas, on a worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I added a macro to copy a worksheet to another worksheet, so that any changes made after that point can be compared to the original. However, my macro copies over formulas instead of just the values, so when something changes, both sheets change, and the copy serves no purpose. What I have is:

```
Worksheets("First Sheet").Cells.Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Second Sheet").Cells
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *Copy >> PasteSpecial* and paste only values, this is a 2-line syntax:

```
Worksheets("First Sheet").Cells.Copy
Worksheets("Second Sheet").Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: If you consider `Application.CutCopyMode = False` then it will be three line syntax.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij yes, and if I add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and then turn it on, it will be 5, the options are endless...

Comment: I wrote it from the viewpoint that `CutCopyMode` blinking continues if 'Application.CutCopyMode = False' line is not added. This doesn't occur with OP's single line code.

Comment: This give me the 'this operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized' error, but they are definitely the same size, as the sheet I'm trying to copy it to is an exact copy of the original.

Answer (score 1):

After your macro, you can write this one:

```
With Worksheets("First Sheet")
    Worksheets("Second Sheet").Range(.UsedRange.Address).Cells.Value2 = .UsedRange.Value2
End With
```

It takes the values of the first sheet and it puts them to the second sheet. The trick with `UsedRange` is needed, because `Worksheets(2).Cells.Value2 = Worksheets(1).Cells.Value2` goes above the usual resources of a normal PC.

Comment: @UncleBajubjubs - welcome. And it is exponentially faster than copying values.

Answer (score 0):

This will skip all formula cells in the first sheet:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim r As Range, addy As String
    For Each r In Worksheets("First Sheet").Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        addy = r.Address
        r.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Second Sheet").Range(addy)
    Next r
End Sub
```